# read data from a database or text file in instruments javascript script

Tags: javascript, ios, database, instruments, ui-automation

I have a script like so:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var mainWindow = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();

var element = mainWindow.textFields()["UserID"];
element.setValue("Hello World");

UIALogger.logStart("Logging element tree ...");
target.logElementTree();
UIALogger.logPass();
```

What I want to do is read a text file or database connection, so I can replace the "Hello World" with either a value from a text file or a database query. Is this possible in the Instruments application with using javascript to control UI Automation for the iphone simulator?

Comment: I am able to create javascript arrays in another file and import that file, but i'd much rather read an xml file, connect to a web service, or query a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can acquire every data that you are able to acquire in a bash script.
Write a script file that prints the desired information to the standard output. For example

```
#!/bin/bash
cat myfile
```

You can run this bash-script from UIAutomation and get the output of it with this command

```
var result = target.host().performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout(full_path_to_your_script, [""], 10);
```

Now your can use the output of your bash script:

```
element.setValue(result.stdout);
```

Comment: can I do this for an imageview control also and set it with the output of a png file?

Comment: @NickTurner, 
I have a similar requirement to read data from another file.
how to write a script file to execute this statement in terminal? 
'cat myfile'

Comment: @NickTurner You can always have your host-side script return json - and that means you can encode anything you want, including image data (just do something like base64-encoded values)

Comment: @fabe can we write data from instruments to a file and save it on the disk ??

Comment: @PrabhuKonchada you can. You just need to write a bash script that will write to a file. Something like echo $1 >> file.json